# Can I use Clutter in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, clutter

I'd like to use a [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) stage as a widget in an SWT window. I'm aware that there are Java [bindings](http://git.clutter-project.org/bindings/jclutter/commit/?id=05bd04571e8ce88cfbf83d0148b196b20b12eb8c) for Clutter, but I'm not sure how to use them (for SWT or otherwise).

I suspect that this might be a bit difficult. If it's prohibitively difficult, then I would appreciate some possible alternatives. However, upon searching, the only alternative to Clutter I could find was Core Animation from Apple (which isn't for Java, obviously). So, the ideal solution would be to get Clutter to work for SWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried JavaFX as an alternative? There is an article here: http://www.sooperarticles.com/technology-articles/operating-system-articles/integration-swing-swt-javafx-2-0-899116.html ,which explains how you can use JavaFX with SWT or Swing.

JavaFX is possibly the closest to Clutter you can get in the Javaworld, without using Clutter.

I have never used the Clutter Java bindings but I suspect that it would not be a trivial task to combine Clutter and SWT.

Comment: Best answer I got to this question in six months.